# WSO2 API Manager not directing to Sandbox based on Sandbox Key

Tags: api, wso2

We have a deployed API which is responding correctly; however it has a different URL endpoint configured for Sandbox vs Production.

When I curl a request to the API Manager it is always the Production endpoint which is hit despite which Bearer token I submit.  Authentication is working as if I submit an invalid Bearer token I get unauthenticated errors.

Any clues of where the mis-configuration might be?

(version 1.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

When looking at your mentioned issue,I think you have used the 'PRODUCTION' scoped access token to invoke your SANDBOX endpoint.

After you defined two different endpoints as sandbox URL and production URL when creating the API,to invoke them you need to use different access tokens based on its scope [PRODUCTION/SANDBOX].

To invoke SANDBOX endpoint from your API,you need to use SANDBOX access token.
To find these production and sandbox endpoints related keys,you can navigate to APIStore->My Subscriptions page and view the keys under sections of 'production' and 'sandbox' in the particular subscription.And under each 'PRODUCTION/SANDBOX' keys section of subscriptions page,you'll see a separate access token and consumer key/secret.

Try invoking your SANDBOX endpoint of API,with above shown sandbox access token in 'My Subscriptions' page of APIStore or else you can use sandbox based consumer key/secret to generate sandbox scoped user tokens[1] and use those tokens to invoke your API sandbox based endpoint.

A sample cURL request to generate sandbox scoped user token would be as below;
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxx&scope=SANDBOX" -H "Authorization :Basic base64encoded_SANDBOX_based_consumer key:secret, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `https://ip:8243/token`

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Token+APIs#TokenAPIs-GeneratingusertokensGenerating